# Exoplayer 2.10.3 implement in java

Tags: java, exoplayer

Currently I'm developing a streaming app.
For the features I need I decided to use Exoplayer.
I couldn't find example code for Exoplayer 2.10.3.
My project is in Java, there is an example in Kotlin but it does not do good for me.

Comment: Typed in "Exoplayer java example" to google and I found a lot of results.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a specific problem, with your attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: The examples you found are deprecated or not working.